# if statement vs. expression

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, toggle, expression

What do you prefer concerning **performance** (memory consumption, speed) / **readability**, if you need to switch variable value between 0 and 1 in a cycle:

```
x=get(x) 
for i in range (start, end):
    if x==0:
        x=1
    else:
        x=0
```

or

```
x=get(x)
for i in range (start, end):
    x = ((x + 1) % 2)
```

How the python compiler interprets it?

Comment: Have a look at the [dis](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html#module-dis) module. Use it, look at the bytecode and come back here if it's something that you don't understand.

Comment: `x = 1 - x` for brevity.

Comment: ..and for a better approach to toggle between values, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986970/python-how-to-toggle-between-two-values

Comment: `x=x^1` also works if `x` is `0` or `1`.

Comment: Thanks for hints, the issue is that initial value of x may not be only 0/1.
And what about the performance comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a multitude of options beyond the `if` statement and expression you used.

- Use subtraction:

  ```
  x = 1 - x
  ```
- Use `^` (XOR):

  ```
  for i in range (start, end):
      x ^= 1
  ```

  This toggles between 0 and 1:

  ```
  >>> x = 1
  >>> x ^ 1
  0
  >>> x ^= 1
  >>> x ^ 1
  1
  ```
- You could use [`itertools.cycle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

  ```
  from itertools import cycle

  x_values = cycle((0, 1))

  for i in range (start, end):
      x = next(x_values)
  ```

  `cycle()` is especially useful for swapping between more than one value, especially when there is no easy mathematical or logical relationship between them:

  ```
  >>> from itertools import cycle
  >>> x_values = cycle((1, 'spam', 3.14))
  >>> next(x_values)
  1
  >>> next(x_values)
  'spam'
  >>> next(x_values)
  3.14
  >>> next(x_values)
  1
  ```

But to figure out which works best for you, pick a metric and stick to that. For performance, use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for comparative trials.

Using `x - 1` is by far faster than `cycle()` or your expression, for example:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('x = 1 - x', 'x = 0')
0.044335126876831055
>>> timeit('x ^= 1', 'x = 0')
0.05133986473083496
>>> timeit('x = ((x + 1) % 2)', 'x = 0')
0.11392998695373535
>>> timeit('x = next(x_values)', 'from itertools import cycle; x_values = cycle((0, 1))')
0.1254570484161377
```

The Python compiler interprets code pretty straightforward, mostly. Your `if` version would not be optimized, for example. Use the [`dis.dis()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) to see a disassembly of the compiler output:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     if x==0:
...         x=1
...     else:
...         x=0
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       21

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             15 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             18 JUMP_FORWARD             6 (to 27)

  5     >>   21 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             24 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
        >>   27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see the full branching structure is still there. Using an expression leads to very different bytecode:

```
>>> def bar():
...     x = ((x + 1) % 2)
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             10 BINARY_MODULO       
             11 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xor operator `^` to toggle between `0` and `1`:

```
x ^= 1
```