# Making a number bigger when its small, and smaller when big

Tags: python, math

i have been coding in python for some time now, and am trying to make a robotic hand in combination with Arduino. I have 2 servo's facing the opposite way (small electric motors) which means that when i rotate them by the same angle, the second one will rotate the opposite way. As the servo can't handle negative integers, i have to come with a solution that basically "reverses" the integer. What i mean by that is that if the number is greater than the middle point (45 in this case) i want it to be smaller, so lets say we have 46 it should be 44 and 47 -> 43 so on. How would i go about creating this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Edit the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to toggle between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986970/how-to-toggle-between-two-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a tricky algorithm:

```
edge = 45
number = 44
result = edge + (edge - number)
```

result will be `46`

```
edge = 45
number = 47
result = edge + (edge - number)
```

result will be `43`

Comment: I will try this out, thanks for the quick response. Very cool to see how its done in such a compact way, thanks!